# Use Codable Protocol on Custom Classes in SpriteKit

Tags: sprite-kit, codable, decodable

I am building an app using SpriteKit, and I would like to save a a complex custom class to NSUserDefaults leveraging the Codable Protocol.  When I do so, I get the following error:

```
Cannot automatically synthesize 'Decodable' because 'SKSpriteNode' does not conform to 'Decodable'
```

The class looks like the following (at least the part with the properties):

```
class TileNode: SKNode, Codable {

    // MARK: - Class Variables

    var height = 32
    var width  = 32
    var index  = 0
    var row    = 0
    var column = 0
    var tileType = ""

    // These cannot be global because each tile needs its own instance of them.
    var dark = SKSpriteNode()
    var light = SKSpriteNode()


    // MARK: - Init

    override init() {
        super.init()

    }

    init(index:Int, tex: String) {
        super.init()

        if tileCheck {
            print("TileNode: init: creating tile with texture: \(tex).")
        }

        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        self.index = index
        self.zPosition = 10
        self.name = "Tile \(index)"
        self.tileType = tex

    }
}
```

So, my question is, how does one use the codable protocol on custom objects when you need to have things like SKSpriteNode as class variables?

Comment: you need to learn how protocols work,  at no point are you using the init(decoder:NSCoder) that the protocol is telling you to add (You also need to add encoder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is obvious that this problem is because `SKSpriteNode` does not conform to `Codable` protocol. So, the following steps enable the custom class Like `SKSpriteNode` to work well using `Codable` protocol.

1. **Declare Custom Coding Keys to define the list of properties to be encoded or decoded**
2. **Implement `required init(from:)`method to convert `Data` into `SKSpriteNode`**
3. **Implement `encode(to:)` method to convert `SKSpriteNode` into `Data`**

Here is the sample:

```
class TileNode: SKNode, Codable {

    var height = 32.0
    var width  = 32.0
    var index  = 0
    var row    = 0
    var column = 0
    var tileType = ""

    // These cannot be global because each tile needs its own instance of them.
    var dark = SKSpriteNode()
    var light = SKSpriteNode()

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case height
        case width
        case index
        case row
        case column
        case tileType
        case dark
        case light
    }

    init(index:Int, tex: String) {
        super.init()

        if tileCheck {
            print("TileNode: init: creating tile with texture: \(tex).")
        }

        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        self.index = index
        self.zPosition = 10
        self.name = "Tile \(index)"
        self.tileType = tex
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        super.init()
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        height = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .height)
        width = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .width)
        index = try values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .index)
        row = try values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .row)
        column = try values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .column)
        tileType = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .tileType)

        let darkData = try values.decode(Data.self, forKey: .dark)
        dark = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: darkData) as? SKSpriteNode ?? SKSpriteNode()
        let lightData = try values.decode(Data.self, forKey: .light)
        light = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: lightData) as? SKSpriteNode ?? SKSpriteNode()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        // subclass of SKNode must implement this method
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        try container.encode(height, forKey: .height)
        try container.encode(width, forKey: .width)
        try container.encode(index, forKey: .index)
        try container.encode(row, forKey: .row)
        try container.encode(column, forKey: .column)
        try container.encode(tileType, forKey: .tileType)

        let darkData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: dark)
        try container.encode(darkData, forKey: .dark)
        let lightData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: light)
        try container.encode(lightData, forKey: .light)
    }

}
```

**Usage**

Encode Data and save Data in UserDefaults:

```
    let node = TileNode(index: 3, tex: "Text")
    node.height = 33.0
    let dark = SKSpriteNode()
    dark.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 12.3, y: 45.6)
    dark.color = UIColor.red
    node.dark = dark
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()

    do {
        let encoded = try encoder.encode(node)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "Node")
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Retrieve Data from UserDefaults and Decode Data:

```
    let docoder = JSONDecoder()
    do {
        let nodeData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "Node") as! Data
        let node = try docoder.decode(TileNode.self, from: nodeData)
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Comment: For the most part this solution works great, but when I try to load from defaults, I get the error "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format." in the console.

Comment: The error occurred in this line `let node = try docoder.decode(TileNode.self, from: nodeData)`?

Comment: That is my assumption, it did not crash the app, it just didn't load the object from user defaults like I thought it would.  However, I am now digging into it to see if I can figure it out.

Comment: Okay, turns out I was a trifle sloppy with my first implementation and forgot to change some variables :P  This solution works as expected, thank you!!!

Comment: I discovered today that there is still a problem with this solution:  it calls for two separate required init functions and the wrong one is being called.  When I try to load a parent of this custom class from user defaults, I get a fatal error on this line: "required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        // subclass of SKNode must implement this method
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }"

Comment: That was disappointing:(  Is “a parent of this class” SKNode?

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  I have been busy at work and this is a pet project.  I am working on it again tonight and I will post what I discover.  I have a few ideas I am working out.  But to answer your question, the parent class is also a SKSpriteNode.

Comment: I am going to write up the problem I am having in a different question, since I think it strays a bit from this question, and I think this question has been successfully answered.

Comment: I created a new question, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50916375/why-isnt-the-codable-init-being-called-instead-of-the-other-required-init

Comment: @zeeple OK. I’m going to check it!